# Issue with PHP form fields and no store to database

Tags: php, forms

I'm learning about php langage and I'm getting an issue according to fill php form fields and data storage.

**First part : form fields**

I overcome to display my form but I can't write data in my fields (except `Date de Naissance` and `Pays`).

Maybe my syntax is bad but I don't understand why I can't populate my fields.

This is part of my script according to my form :

```
// Get parameters
$id         = GETPOST('id', 'int');
$ref        = GETPOST('ref', 'alpha');
$action     = GETPOST('action', 'alpha');
$cancel     = GETPOST('cancel', 'aZ09');
$backtopage = GETPOST('backtopage', 'alpha');

// Initialize technical objects
$object=new MyObject($db);

// If create a request
if ($action == 'create')
{
        $object = new FormFile($db);

        $db->begin();

            $nom = GETPOST('nom');
            $prenom = GETPOST('prenom');
            $datenaissance = dol_mktime(0, 0, 0, GETPOST('datenaissance_month'), GETPOST('datenaissance_day'), GETPOST('datenaissance_year'));
            $adresse=GETPOST('adresse');
            $codepostal=GETPOST('codepostal');
                $pays=GETPOST('pays');

        // If no name
            if (empty($nom))
            {
                setEventMessages($langs->trans("Pas de nom"), null, 'errors');
                $error++;
                $action='create';
            }

        // If no firstname
            if (empty($prenom))
            {
                setEventMessages($langs->trans("Pas de prénom"), null, 'errors');
                $error++;
                $action='create';
            }

        // If no birthday
            if (empty($datenaissance))
            {
                setEventMessages($langs->trans("Pas de date de naissance"), null, 'errors');
                $error++;
                $action='create';
            }

        // If no address
            if (empty($adresse))
            {
                setEventMessages($langs->trans("Pas d'adresse"), null, 'errors');
                $error++;
                $action='create';
            }

        // If no code postal
            if (empty($codepostal))
            {
                setEventMessages($langs->trans("Pas de code postal"), null, 'errors');
                $error++;
                $action='create';
            }

            $result = 0;

            if (! $error)
            {
                $object->nom = $nom;
                $object->prenom = $prenom;
                $object->datenaissance = $datenaissance;
                $object->adresse = $adresse;
                $object->codepostal = $codepostal;
                    $object->pays = $pays;
                    $result = $object->create($user);
             if ($result <= 0)
                {
                        setEventMessages($object->errors, 'errors');
                        $error++;
                }
            }

// If no SQL error we redirect to the request card
            if (! $error)
            {
                $db->commit();

                header('Location: '.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'?id='.$object->id);
                exit;
            }
            else
                {
                $db->rollback();
            }
}


/*
 * View
 *
 * Put here all code to build page
 */

$form=new Form($db);
$formfile=new FormFile($db);
llxHeader('', $langs->trans('Formulaire de test'));

// Part to create
if ($action == 'create')
{
    // Formulaire de demande de congés payés
        print load_fiche_titre($langs->trans('Formulaire de test'), '', 'title_hrm.png');

    // Formulaire de demande
        print '<form method="POST" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" onsubmit="return valider()" name="Formulaire de test">'."\n";
        print '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="create" />'."\n";

        dol_fiche_head();

        print '<table class="border" width="100%">';
        print '<tbody>';

    // Nom
        print '<tr>';
        print '<td class="fieldrequired">'.$langs->trans("Nom").'</td>';
        print '<td>';
        print '<input type="hidden" name="nom" value="'.$object->nom.'">';
        print '</td></tr>';

    // Prenom
        print '<tr>';
        print '<td class="fieldrequired">'.$langs->trans("Prenom").'</td>';
        print '<td>';
        print '<input type="hidden" name="prenom" value="'.$object->prenom.'">';
        print '</td></tr>';

    // Date Naissance
        print '<tr>';
        print '<td class="fieldrequired">'.$langs->trans("Date de Naissance").'</td>';
        print '</td>';
        print '<td>';
        if (! GETPOST('datenaissance')) {
            $form->select_date(-1, 'datenaissance', 0, 0, 0, '', 1, 1);
        } else {
            $tmpdate = dol_mktime(0, 0, 0, GETPOST('datenaissance_month'), GETPOST('datenaissance_day'), GETPOST('datenaissance_year'));
            $form->select_date($tmpdate, 'datenaissance', 0, 0, 0, '', 1, 1);
        }
        print '</td>';
        print '</tr>';

    // Adresse
        print '<tr>';
        print '<td class="fieldrequired">'.$langs->trans("Adresse").'</td>';
        print '<td>';
        print '<input type="hidden" name="adresse" value="'.$object->adresse.'">';
        print '</td></tr>';

    // Code Postal
        print '<tr>';
        print '<td class="fieldrequired">'.$langs->trans("Code Postal").'</td>';
        print '<td>';
        print '<input type="hidden" name="codepostal" value="'.$object->codepostal.'">';
        print '</td></tr>';

    // Country
        print '<tr><td>'.fieldLabel('Pays','selectcountry_id').'</td><td class="maxwidthonsmartphone">';
        print $form->select_country((GETPOST('country_id')!=''?GETPOST('country_id'):$object->pays));
        if ($user->admin) print info_admin($langs->trans("YouCanChangeValuesForThisListFromDictionarySetup"),1);
        print '</td></tr>';

        print '</tbody>';
        print '</table>';

        dol_fiche_end();

        print '<div class="center">';
        print '<input type="submit" value="'.$langs->trans("Valider le formulaire").'" name="bouton" class="button">';
        print '&nbsp; &nbsp; ';
        print '<input type="button" value="'.$langs->trans("Cancel").'" class="button" onclick="history.go(-1)">';
        print '</div>';

        print '</form>'."\n";
}
// End of page
llxFooter();
$db->close();
```

In order to populate each field, this syntax is good ?

```
print '<input type="hidden" name="myfieldname" value="'.$object->field.'">';
```

As you can see, fields can't be fill (except `Date de Naissance` and `Pays`)

[image]

**Second part :**

I don't overcome to save data in my database when I click on `submit` button. I'm getting all the time this issue `Pas de date de naissance` in my form page.

**EDIT :**

I think that `type="hidden"` was the issue ? If I write `text` it seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hidden fields are not meant to be filled by the user:

> elements of type "hidden" let web developers include data that cannot be seen or modified by users when a form is submitted
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden

Comment: It's true, I replaced `hidden` by `text` and it seems to work. But I don't just overcome to save my form in my database.

Comment: Although it is clear what they are trying to say, but '...data that cannot be seen', is not entirely true, a user could look at the source of the page and see what's in hidden form-fields.